# What scrolling / list control is used on Windows 10 store?

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm playing around with Windows Universal App development. When looking at the Windows 10 Store App, I noticed a scrolling list control as shown in the below screenshot. Clicking the right arrow will shift right by a certain number of elements. Likewise on the other side, clicking the left arrow will shift back.

Is the scrolling control in the Store App a standard control or something custom made?

I'm aware of things like the ScrollViewer, but that just adds a scroll bar.

[image]

Comment: I think this is custom made. Scrolling control in UWP are ListView, GridView, ListBox. Then you can set the arrow on both side to scroll the list to certain offset if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this by the following:

- Grid with 3 columns with widths 3*, 94*, 3*
- First column contains `Button` stretched vertically and horizontally to fill the grid and a `ListView`
- Second column contains nothing
- Third column contains `Button` stretched vertically and horizontally to fill the grid and a `ListView`
- Button clicks fire events to calculate how many places to scroll left or right and then uses `ListView.ScrollIntoView` to scroll the items into view